# AAPT2 error when building Android App on ARM64

Tags: android

I have a Drone.io build CI / CD on a ARM64 based CPU (Oracle) and in the Docker I have Java 11 and latest commandline tools from Google.

When I run the command: ./gradlew assembleRelease I get a AAPT2 error:

```
AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/468547271df0fd777495680b526c836b/transformed/aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux/aapt2: 1: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/468547271df0fd777495680b526c836b/transformed/aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux/aapt2: 3: y?: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/468547271df0fd777495680b526c836b/transformed/aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux/aapt2: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/468547271df0fd777495680b526c836b/transformed/aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux/aapt2: 1: cannot open l: No such file
AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/468547271df0fd777495680b526c836b/transformed/aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux/aapt2: 1: yP?tdppp: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Unexpected error output: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/468547271df0fd777495680b526c836b/transformed/aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux/aapt2: 3: K??H??H??HH=JH]JH]JR?td??H??H??H@qa: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/468547271df0fd777495680b526c836b/transformed/aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux/aapt2: 1: ELF: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/468547271df0fd777495680b526c836b/transformed/aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux/aapt2: 3: y?: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/468547271df0fd777495680b526c836b/transformed/aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux/aapt2: 1: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")
AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/468547271df0fd777495680b526c836b/transformed/aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux/aapt2: 1: cannot open l: No such file
AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/468547271df0fd777495680b526c836b/transformed/aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux/aapt2: 1: yP?tdppp: not found
AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #1: Unexpected error output: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/468547271df0fd777495680b526c836b/transformed/aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux/aapt2: 3: K??H??H??HH=JH]JH]JR?td??H??H??H@qa: not found
> Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Failed to transform appcompat-1.4.1.aar (androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/19075c4677e37e538c54d7f745fc8af4/transformed/appcompat-1.4.1.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #1: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.7.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.dependency.bundling=external, org.gradle.libraryelements=aar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/9339927e08badd09bc5459e4ba900d5f/transformed/core-1.7.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.7.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/9339927e08badd09bc5459e4ba900d5f/transformed/core-1.7.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.7.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/9339927e08badd09bc5459e4ba900d5f/transformed/core-1.7.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.7.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/9339927e08badd09bc5459e4ba900d5f/transformed/core-1.7.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.7.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/9339927e08badd09bc5459e4ba900d5f/transformed/core-1.7.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.7.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/9339927e08badd09bc5459e4ba900d5f/transformed/core-1.7.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.7.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/9339927e08badd09bc5459e4ba900d5f/transformed/core-1.7.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.7.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/9339927e08badd09bc5459e4ba900d5f/transformed/core-1.7.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.7.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/9339927e08badd09bc5459e4ba900d5f/transformed/core-1.7.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.7.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/9339927e08badd09bc5459e4ba900d5f/transformed/core-1.7.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
           This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
   > Failed to transform core-1.7.0.aar (androidx.core:core:1.7.0) to match attributes {artifactType=android-compiled-dependencies-resources, org.gradle.status=release}.
      > Execution failed for AarResourcesCompilerTransform: /drone/src/gradle_cache/caches/transforms-3/9339927e08badd09bc5459e4ba900d5f/transformed/core-1.7.0.
         > AAPT2 aapt2-7.0.4-7396180-linux Daemon #0: Daemon startup failed
```

The project builds fine on Windows and I also tried to run gradlew clean before assembleRelease but that did not help either, I have set GRADLE_USER_HOME to another folder but also that did not help.

Comment: AFAIK - There isn't a arm version of Android Studio for linux, only for mac. @StreY how did you get around this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need same aapt2 version,but another architecture,because Android studio use amd64 from aapt,aapt2 version

Comment: AFAIK - There isn't a arm version of Android Studio for linux, only for mac. @StreY how did you get around this issue?